# CopyOnWriteArrayList: Why do we have to make a full copy of source data?

Tags: java, collections

I have a lot of confusion about Java's [CopyOnWriteArrayist](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). I know, when we have a modification on it like update, insert of set, it will lock the whole list, copy out a total copy of the source list, do the modification and then release the lock. So, My question is:

1. When doing the modification, why cannot we just lock the array, do the modification and finally release the lock? Why we have to make a new copy of the array?
2. The write lock is only effective for a concurrent modification, but not for a modification and read. When we are doing a read, we read from the old array and get the old data, right?

Answer (score 4):

> 1.When doing the modification, why cannot we just lock the array, do the modification and finally release the lock? Why we have to make a new copy of the array?

Because if you were to lock on write and don't create a new copy you will also have to lock on read which would be a bottleneck. You can have this functionality with `Collections.synchronizedList(list)`. With `CopyOnWriteArrayList` there is no lock on read, which means is faster. Because of this `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is only useful when you have few updates and inserts and many concurrent reads.

> 2.The write lock is only effective for a concurrent modification, but not for a modification and read. When we are doing a read, we read from the old array and get the old data, right?

Yes. If you are iterating over the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and while iterating a write is made concurrently, then your `Iterator` is not aware of the changes. You'll have to start iterating again after the update, to have the latest data.